# how to handle backslashes and quotation mark in spark sql?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark-sql

there is a json string in the field kv of one spark sql table;
such as

```
{"cpu_max_freq":"1401000","net_ok":"2","ad_report_status":"1\"}"}
```

how to select this line by using sql?

I have tried :

```
select * from table_a where get_json_object(kv, "$.ad_report_status") = '1\\"}'
select * from table_a where get_json_object(kv, "$.ad_report_status") = '1\"}'
select * from table_a where get_json_object(kv, "$.ad_report_status") = '1\\\"}'
select * from table_a where get_json_object(kv, "$.ad_report_status") = '1\\\"}'
```

none of above sql works !!

so how to match the value of  "ad_report_status" field ?

Comment: You may store and retrieve data by encoding and decoding.

Comment: someone store the json into the table, but I can't search it out. I know that I should handle the special character such as \ " ， but every try has failed .